# Getting direction vectors from 3d position and/or rotation

Tags: math, vector, 3d, camera

I have a camera, in which, I've obtained its 3d position and its 3d rotation (in degrees). The coordinate system is as follows:

The order is XYZ and is intrinsic.

- pitch
- roll
- yaw

(aka right/front/top vector)

With this information, how can I calculate the Up and Front vectors?

Comment: Specify how rotation is defined.

Comment: It's properly updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Yaw rotation is about OY (vertical) axis and has matrix MY (for CCW positive)

```
 Cos(Yaw)   -Sin(Yaw)   0
 Sin(Yaw)   Cos(Yaw)    0
 0          0          1
```

Pitch rotation is about OZ axis and has matrix MP

```
 Cos(Pitch)    0    Sin(Pitch)
 0            1    0
 -Sin(Pitch)   0    Cos(Yaw)
```

Roll rotation is about OX axis and has matrix MR

```
 1      0           0     
 0      Cos(Roll)   -Sin(Roll)
 0      Sin(Roll)   Cos(Roll)
```

Now one has to multiply matrices MP, MR, MY in right order and get matrix M. 
To find forward direction vector - multiply M and vector [1, 0, 0]. To get top direction vector -  multiply M and vector [0, 1, 0]. To get side direction vector - multiply M and vector [1, 0, 0].

I cannot check right matrix multiplication order and the last result now. If you have any symbolic math software like Maple, Matlab - try it.

Result should look like this for forward

```
X = Cos(Pitch) * Cos(Yaw)
Y = Sin(Pitch)
Z = Cos(Pitch) * Sin(Yaw)
```

and up (perhaps wrong)

```
X = -Cos(Yaw) * Sin(Roll) - Sin(Yaw) * Sin(Pitch) * Cos(Roll)
Y = Sin(Yaw) * Sin(Roll) - Cos(Yaw) * Sin(Pitch) * Cos(Roll)
Z = Cos(Pitch) * Cos(Roll)
```